# Can't get correct keycode

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, key

I'm trying to write a function that detects if the pressed key is a number or not, but it's not working correctly because sometimes it lets non-numbers "pass" the test (more specifically, these keys: e, i, a, d, f, g, h, c, b and the grave accent). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but I guess it has something to do with my brazilian keyboard with some extra keys (or not).

JS Code:

```
function myFunction (e) {
    if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) ||
    (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
        // do something
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid key");
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // the script is here
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onkeypress="myFunction(event)">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this part: `||  (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)`.
Those key codes [correspond to `a-i`.](http://www.asciitable.com/)